# Prove two equation about $H_{p} (X) $ and $kernel\ (i_{n_{*}})_{p}\ $ .

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am new with [singular homology](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/singular+homology#Definition)
This is a fair but hard exercise for all of my classmate, we all feel dizzy after Imagine what really happen during the procedure of the question and what it really says.

Suppose $X$ is a topological space.

and $\{U_{n}\mid n \geq 0\}$ is a open cover of $X$ such that $\forall n, U_{n} \subseteq U_{n+1}$.

Let $i_{m,n}\colon U_{n} \rightarrow U_{m}$ and $i_{n}\colon U_{n} \rightarrow X $ denote the inclusion maps.

***The problem is to show that***

**1)** $H_{p} (X) =  \bigcup^{\infty} _{n=0} Im((i_{n_*})_{p})$, and

**2)** $ker((i_{n_*})_{p}) =  \bigcup^{\infty} _{m=n} ker((i_{m,n*})_{p}) $

Well as far as I knew we have $\Delta^{n} = \{{ (x_{0}, ..., x_{n}) \in R^{n+1} | x_{i} \geq 0, \sum _{i} x_{i}=1 \}}$ called n-simplex.

for a singular homology we define a chain complex:

$\hspace{3 cm}...\rightarrow S_{n+1}(X) \rightarrow^{\partial _{n+1}} S_{n}(X) \rightarrow^{\partial _{n}} S_{n-1}(X) \rightarrow ...$

where:

$\hspace{4 cm} S_{n}(X):=\{{ \sigma \ |\ \sigma: \Delta^{n} \rightarrow X  \}}$

and we say $S_{n}(X)$ is a free abelian group based on singular n-simplices.

the chain map is defined as:

$\hspace{4 cm} \partial_{n}: S_{n}(X)\rightarrow S_{n-1}(X)$

$\hspace{5 cm}\sigma \hspace{0.6 cm} \rightarrow \sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^{i}\sigma^{(i)}$

where $\sigma$ are continouos amd injection maps.

$\hspace{4 cm}\partial_{n} \sigma := \sum^{n}_{k=0}(-1)^{k}[p_{0},...,p_{k-1},p_{k+1},..p_{n}]$

on the other hand it means:

$\hspace{4 cm}\partial_{n}\sigma = \sigma|_{faces\ of\ \Delta^{n}}$

As this is a chain complex and by the definition of boundary operation $\partial^{n}$ it is can be shown that:

$\hspace{4 cm} \partial^{n}\circ \partial^{n+1}=0$

n-th homology group of X is defined as a quotient space:

$\hspace{4 cm} H_{n}(x)= \frac{kernel\ \partial^{n}}{Image\ \partial^{n+1}}$

and we call $H_{n}(f)$ the **induced map**, and we usually denote it by $f_{n}*$ or $f_{*}$.

$\hspace{4 cm}(i_{n_{*}})_{p}:\ H_{p}(U_{n})\rightarrow H_{p}(X)$

Comment: What exactly does $\mathrm{im}((i_n)_p)$ mean?

Comment: I assume $(i_n)_p$ is the induced map $H_p(i_n) : H_p(U_n) \to H_p(X)$; this could be made a little clearer if so.

Comment: yes thank you @QiaochuYuan

Comment: Do you know the definition of the singular homology of a space (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology)? The reference in your question is about a homology of a chain complex, but you further need to know how to construct a chain complex from a space. If you know it, my answer should be fairly complete (or at least you can ask me in the comment where you don't understand).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful comment and link, I truly don't get your answer how the equations been is proven. my constructed chain is : $U_{0}\rightarrow U_{1}\rightarrow ... \rightarrow U_{n}\rightarrow ...\rightarrow X$ but contructed chain complex from an existed simplicial complex K is $K\rightarrow^{boundary of K}...$ correct me please if I am wrong. @NarukiMasuda

Comment: A chain complex is a sequence of abelian groups $d_n: M_n\to M_{n+1}$ satisfying $d_n\circ d_{n+1}=0$. Now your $U_i$'s are not abelian groups, and even if you take an appropriate algebraic invariant, the composite won't be $0$. The correct chain complex to define $H_p(X)$ is given as follows: $M_p$ is the free abelian group generated by the set of all continuous maps $\Delta^p\to X$, and the differential is given by the alternating sum of face maps. If this doesn't ring a bell, you don't know the definition of $H_p(X)$, so I recommend you open whatever textbook of topology and learn it first.

Comment: I know $H_{p} (\Delta_{p})$ or $H_{p} (C_{i})$ for any abelian group $C_{i}$ or $H_{p}$ of any element in a chain complex but I really don't get the definition of $H_{p} (X)$ without any chain complex including $X$ as an element, help please @NarukiMasuda

Comment: $X$ is not a chain complex, so your definition just doesn't apply directly. Also, homology is not something defined for a single abelian group or an element in a chain complex. I don't know where did you come across the problem, but you're not in the right context, and it's more than what I can explain here (it may take a whole lecture to explain what it is). Please just take some time and read, say, section 2.1 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

Comment: Your definition of $S_p(X)$ is wrong, elements of $S_p(X)$ is of the form $\sigma= \sum_i \sigma_i$, where the right hand side is a finite formal sum of $\sigma_i: \Delta^p\to X$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

edit: I think my former answer is clearer, but anyway I try to write the answer as detailed as possible.

Using the compactness of $\Delta^p$, the image of any singular simplex $\Delta^p\to X$ (which is also compact) is contained in some $U_n$. Since any $p$-cycle $\sigma$ of $X$ is a *finite* formal sum $\sum_i \sigma_i$ of singular simplices $\sigma_i: \Delta^p \to X$, we can find $n$ such that $U_n$ contains the image of all $\sigma_i$'s (by taking the maximum of $n_i$'s such that the image of $\sigma_i$ is contained in $U_{n_i}$.) This means that there exists $\sigma_i': \Delta^p\to U_n$ such that $i_n\circ \sigma_i' = \sigma_i$. Define $\sigma' = \sum_i\sigma_i'$, so that $(i_n)_\ast \sigma'=\sigma$.

Now let $[\sigma]\in H_p(X)$ be the homology class represented by the $p$-cycle $\sigma$. To prove the first statement, it suffices to prove that $[\sigma]$ is in the image of $H_p(U_n)\to H_{p}(X)$. This is true because $(i_n)_\ast [\sigma'] = [\sigma]$.

For the second, let $\sigma=\sum_i{\sigma_i}$ (where $\sigma_i$'s are singular $p$-simplices) be a $p$-cycle in $U_n$ and suppose $[\sigma]\in H_p(U_n)$ satisfies $(i_n)_\ast [\sigma] = 0$. By definition this means that there exists a $(p+1)$-cycle $\tau = \sum_j \tau_j$ in $X$ such that $\partial \tau =(i_n)_\ast\sigma$ as $p$-cycles of $X$. By exactly the same argument as above, there exists $m\geq n$ such that $U_m$ contains all the images of $\tau_j$'s. Now define $(p+1)$-simplices $\tau'_j: \Delta^{p+1}\to U_m$  and a $(p+1)$-cycles $\tau' = \sum_j \tau'_j$ in $U_m$ as above. Obsereve that $(i_m)_\ast\partial \tau' = \partial (i_m)_\ast \tau' = \partial \tau = (i_n)_\ast \sigma = (i_m)_\ast(i_{m, n})_\ast \sigma$ as $p$-cycles of $X$. Since $(i_m)_\ast: S_p(U_m)\to S_p(X)$ is injective, this implies $\partial\tau' = (i_{m, n})_\ast \sigma$ as $p$-cycles in $U_m$. This means that, in $H_p(U_m)$, we have $(i_{m, n})_\ast[\sigma] = [\partial \tau']=0$, and thus any $[\sigma]\in \ker((i_n)_\ast)$ is contained in $\ker((i_{m, n})_\ast)$ for some $m$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not strong in topology and analysis. Could you elaborate more on the usage of compactness, I mean how did compactness help in first and second statement? thanks in advance.

Comment: and why is $\Delta^p$ compact any way? The families of open covering is not finite for X.

Comment: which means we don't know if X is compact, right?

Comment: $\Delta^p$ is a topological space which is completely independent of $X$, namely, $\{(x_0, \ldots, x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid x_i\geq 0, \sum_i x_i =1\}$. This is compact because it's bounded and closed. A singular simplex of $X$ is by definition a continuous map $\sigma: \Delta^p\to X$, whose image is compact because any continuous image of a compact space is compact.

Comment: Great, Thanks alot

Comment: for the first statement, knowing the fact that for any $\sigma : \Delta^{p}\rightarrow X$, Image $\sigma \subseteq U_{n}$ for some n. how any p-cycle of X is contained in some $U_{n}$???

Comment: since $H_{p} = ker \partial _{p}/ Im \partial _{p+1}$ p-cycles in X are elements of $ker \partial _{p}$.  but what happend to $Im \partial _{p+1}$? we know that $Im \partial _{p+1} \subseteq ker \partial _{p}$ but how its resuts is that $H_{p}$ is equal to p-cycle of X? thanks.

Comment: If you extend your answer and clarify your deduction to be clear how this results to those equation for both statements, then I would be able to bontied  50 points your answer and close that deal (just 3 days left).

Comment: So don't postpone it,  do it for all those who will see and are new to singular homology, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

for the first statement we can say, $\Delta^{p}$ s are closed and bounded so are compact and since $\sigma :\Delta^{p} \rightarrow X$ are continous maps then It induced a compact space on X so Image of the $\sigma$ is also compact.

by e theorem a compact subspace (here $\Delta^{p}$) of a space (here X ) that bigger have a covering the subspace have a finite covering {if I am using a right theorem!}.

thus, Image $\sigma \subseteq \bigcup^{m}_{k=0} U_{k}$. meaning that finite number of $U_{k}$s cover the Image $\sigma$ since the $U_{n}$s are nested we could find the one k for $U_{k}$ and bring up all $U_{i}$ from 0 to k.

now for $S_{p}(X) = \{{\sigma \ |\ \sigma: \Delta^{p}\rightarrow X  \}}$ we have:

$\hspace{4 cm} S_{p}(X)=S_{p}(\bigcup_{0}^{k} U_{i})= S_{p}(U_{k})$

and coresponding to boundary map $\partial_{p}: S_{p}(X)\rightarrow S_{p-1}(X)$ we can rewrite it to:

$\hspace{4 cm}\partial_{p}:S_{p}(U_{k})\rightarrow S_{p-1}(U_{k})$

remember; $(i_{n*})_p: H_{p}(U_{n}) \rightarrow H_{p}(X)$

can say; $\bigcup_{0}^{\infty} Image(i_{n*})_p = Image \bigcup_{0}^{\infty} H_{p}(U_{n}) \rightarrow  H_{p}(X)$

we can show that :

$\hspace{4 cm}Image (i_{n*})_{p} \subseteq H_{p}(X)$

and so:

$\forall n\in N\;\hspace{4 cm} Image (i_{n*})_{p} \subseteq H_{p}(U_{k})$

then:

$\hspace{4 cm}\bigcup ^{\infty} _{0} Image (i_{n*})_{p}\subseteq H_{p}(X)$

and because:

$\hspace{4 cm} H_{p}(U_{k})\subseteq \bigcup ^{\infty} _{0} Image (i_{n*})_{p}$

then:

$\hspace{4 cm} H_{p}(X) \subseteq \bigcup ^{\infty} _{0} Image (i_{n*})_{p}$

thus:

$\hspace{4 cm} H_{p}(X)\ = \ \bigcup ^{\infty} _{0} Image (i_{n*})_{p}$

Comment: $S_p(U_k) = S_p(X)$ is not true because $k$ depends on $\sigma$, but $\bigcup_k S_p(U_k) = S_p(X)$ is true and that's enough for the rest of the argument.